# Picture Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: `identify

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, minimagick

been trying to upload photos with Carrierwave::MiniMagick, installed both gems but i get this error when trying to upload:

> > Picture Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: `identify C:/Users/JOHNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/mini_magick20160918-2884-cgqjcw.png` failed with error: identify: UnableToOpenConfigureFile `magic.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/709. identify: UnableToOpenConfigureFile`delegates.xml' @ warning/configure.c/GetConfigureOptions/709. identify: UnableToOpenModuleFile 'C:\ImageMagick-7.0.2-Q16\modules\coders\IM_MOD_RL_PNG_.dll': No such file or directory @ warning/module.c/GetMagickModulePath/680. identify: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `PNG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/508.

On page reload, the result page displays but the image doesn't.

This is my uploader:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  version :thumb do
     process :resize_to_limit => [200, 200]
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

This is my model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

This is my migration file:

```
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
        t.string :title
        t.text :body
        t.string :picture
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Please any idea guys???....Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution!!! I moved my ImageMagick installation folder to the same path as my sites folder. It now works flawlessly....yayy!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got this error because I was decoding a base64 encoded image string, and I didn't remove the `data:image/png;base64,` header at the start of the string.

**Base64 Encoded Image:**

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0...
```

After removing those first 22 characters before decoding, it all worked fine.